# How to run a Jenkins Build from Command Line?

Tags: jenkins, command-line-interface

After downloading the jenkins jenkins-cli.jar file for its built-in command line interface, I am prompted by the tutorials that I found online to execute the following command at the command prompt in order to run it:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ help
```

But when I enter this command, the following error is returned:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile jenkins-cli.jar

I don't know why this is returned. Could it be connected with me using a Windows machine? Why does this happen, and how could it eventually run?

Answer (score 1):

`https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/` **refer to HTTP connection mode**
Authentication is preferably with an -auth option, which takes a username:apitoken argument. Get your API token from /me/configure:

```
**java -jar jenkins-cli.jar [-s JENKINS_URL] -auth kohsuke:abc1234ffe4a command ...**
```

(Actual passwords are also accepted, but this is discouraged.)

You can also precede the argument with @ to load the same content from a file:

**`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar [-s JENKINS_URL] -auth @/home/kohsuke/.jenkins-cli command ...`**
Generally no special system configuration need be done to enable HTTP-based CLI connections. If you are running Jenkins behind an HTTP(S) reverse proxy, ensure it does not buffer request or response bodies.

Comment: After following the instructions on the link that you shared, I still get the same problem. I am unable to access the jarfile jenkins-cli.jar

Answer (score 1):

This message just means that jenkins-cli.jar is not in either your $PATH or in the same directory you are running java.

Here, jenkins-cli.jar file is in my $HOME/bin directory. At first I try to run it from my $HOME

```
➜  ~ java -jar jenkins-cli.jar                                                                                               
Error: Unable to access jarfile jenkins-cli.jar
```

Now from $HOME/bin

```
➜  ~ cd bin
➜  ~/bin ls -al jenkins-cli.jar    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 2849829 juin  23 10:04 jenkins-cli.jar
➜  ~/bin java -jar jenkins-cli.jar 
Neither -s nor the JENKINS_URL env var is specified.
Jenkins CLI
Usage: java -jar jenkins-cli.jar [-s URL] command [opts...] args...
Options:
-s URL       : the server URL (defaults to the JENKINS_URL env var)
-http        : use a plain CLI protocol over HTTP(S) (the default; mutually exclusive with -ssh and -remoting)
-ssh         : use SSH protocol (requires -user; SSH port must be open on server, and user must have registered a public key)
-remoting    : use deprecated Remoting channel protocol (if enabled on server; for compatibility with legacy commands or command modes only)
-i KEY       : SSH private key file used for authentication (for use with -ssh or -remoting)
-p HOST:PORT : HTTP proxy host and port for HTTPS proxy tunneling. See https://jenkins.io/redirect/cli-https-proxy-tunnel
-noCertificateCheck : bypass HTTPS certificate check entirely. Use with caution
-noKeyAuth   : dont try to load the SSH authentication private key. Conflicts with -i
-user        : specify user (for use with -ssh)
-strictHostKey : request strict host key checking (for use with -ssh)
-logger FINE : enable detailed logging from the client
-auth [ USER:SECRET | @FILE ] : specify username and either password or API token (or load from them both from a file);
for use with -http, or -remoting but only when the JNLP agent port is disabled

The available commands depend on the server. Run the help command to
see the list.
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it has (I think) nothing todo with the connection itself but with being in the same folder as the jar file.

If it can not access the jar file you are probably not in the same directory as the jar file when you perform the `java -jar ...` command.

Start the terminal and change director (`cd <folder>`) to where you downloaded the jar file and try again.